# How can we add a time-range selector in a table in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-table

I want to add a time range selector in a React Table or any other Table like this:

[image: time-range-selector]

**This selector is available in Highcharts and I want to implement this thing in a table. Is there a way to do that?**

Currently, I am using React Table like this:

```
      <ReactTable
      fullWidth
      data={rows}
      columns={columns}
      defaultPageSize={10}
      className="-striped -highlight"
    />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please elaborate the user experience here? Do you need it inside a table cell or do you need to adjust the data based on the time-range selector?

Comment: I need to adjust the data based on the time-range selector.